# converting string into hex in js

Tags: javascript, string, node.js, hex

im using node.js and I have a string that I am trying to convert into hex.

This is the function I'm using:

```
function toHex(str) {
    var hex = '';
    var i = 0;
    while(str.length > i) {
        hex += ''+str.charCodeAt(i).toString(16);
        i++;
    }
    return hex;
}
```

And this is how I am trying to call it:

```
console.log('Payload: ' + toHex(decryptedPayload));
```

However when it runs I get this error:

> ```
>             hex += ''+str.charCodeAt(i).toString(16);
>                           ^ TypeError: undefined is not a function
> at toHex (C:\Users\Office\Desktop\luigi-master\lib\middleware.js:131:17)
> at Middleware._transform (C:\Users\Office\Desktop\luigi-master\lib\middleware.js:161:29)
> at Middleware.Transform._read (_stream_transform.js:179:10)
> at Middleware.Transform._write (_stream_transform.js:167:12)
> at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:301:12)
> at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:288:5)
> at Middleware.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:217:11)
> at Packetize.ondata (_stream_readable.js:540:20)
> at Packetize.emit (events.js:107:17)
> at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:163:16)
> ```

Comment: What type is `decryptedPayload`? Is it a Buffer (`Buffer.isBuffer(decryptedPayload) === true`)? If it's a Buffer, you can just do `decryptedPayload.toString('hex')`

Answer (score 5):

If you have a Buffer, you can call [`toString()`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_tostring_encoding_start_end) directly and pass the kind of output you want, for example: `decryptedPayload.toString('hex')`